# Perforce - Cannot delete shelf with obliterated files

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have this shelf set of files which existed at one point. Now, the files don't exist. I obliterated them. This is causing me issues where I cannot delete this workspace or delete the shelf... Does anyone know how to delete a shelf with obliterated files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete the shelf as normal, regardless of whether the associated depot files have been obliterated:

```
C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 opened
//stream/child_stream/shelf/bar#1 - add default change (text)
//stream/child_stream/shelf/foo#1 - edit default change (text)

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 shelve
Change 279 created with 2 open file(s).
Shelving files for change 279.
add //stream/child_stream/shelf/bar#1
edit //stream/child_stream/shelf/foo#1
Change 279 files shelved.

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 obliterate -y ...
//stream/child_stream/shelf/foo#1 - purged
Deleted 1 client 2 opened 1 revision record(s).

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 files @=279
//stream/child_stream/shelf/bar#none - add change 279 (text)
//stream/child_stream/shelf/foo#1 - edit change 279 (text)

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 shelve -d -c 279
Shelved change 279 deleted.

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 files @=279
@=279 - no file(s) at that changelist number.

C:\Perforce\test\shelf>p4 change -d 279
Change 279 deleted.
```

Note that obliterating `foo` from the depot did not affect the `foo` in the shelf, and did not prevent me from deleting it.

Comment: Hi Sam. I get this error: https://i.imgur.com/mrQtAFO.png

When I try to delete from the p4v UI I get "No shelved files" but the shelve still exists. The same is true in the command line

Comment: Does `p4 files @=457` at the command line show you any shelved files?  If not (and I'd expect it wouldn't) you should be clear to `p4 change -d 457` to delete the empty changelist, which in turn unblocks deleting the client spec.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WdxxLAD.png This is what I get when I run p4 files on that CL

Comment: Two possibilities: **(1)** you don't have `list` permission to see the shelved files (meaning you can't see them in `p4 files`, or delete them with `p4 shelve -d`, but they're still there), or **(2)** there's some kind of db inconsistency.  Either way, first step is to check with your Perforce admin; once you eliminate the permissions possibility, the admin should follow up with Perforce tech support to debug the possible db issue.

Comment: Hey Sam, I'm the perforce admin. My account has super permissions in `p4 protect` How can I check for db inconsistency? I'm not sure how to resolve this type of issue sadly.

Comment: If I run p4d -xx I get these results: https://i.imgur.com/2qTEa0L.png

Comment: Should either contact Perforce support or post on the Perforce forums.  Debugging a possible db inconsistency isn't really suitable for SO since it might require grepping through your checkpoint etc.